# Representing the most recently clicked D3 node in a text field

Tags: d3.js

Observe this beautiful, collapsible radial tree (not my work):

http://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/pcoFz

Here's a little chunk of the data that sits behind it:

```
var pubs =
{
    "name": "AUT-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "PUB-1","children": [
                {"name": "AUT-11","children": [
                    {"name": "AFF-111"},
                    {"name": "AFF-112"}
                ]},
```

I would like to add an additional dimension like ID:

```
{"name": "AFF-111", id:"aff_111"},
```

The tricky part is that I would like to present the ID of the most recently clicked node (if it has one) in a text field. Is this possible or am I pushing the boundaries of sensible D3 behaviour?

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code in the node click listener function to display the id information for each node. Specifically:

```
function click(d) {
  d3.select("#text").html("<p>" + d.id + "</p>")
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

 update(d);
}
```

Example plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zudi8MFiGXnNWbLBeCkg?p=preview). (I only added id data for 'Pub-6 nodes', the same works for the rest of nodes after you add 'id' in source data).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks very much.